# find not working right

Tags: bash, scripting, symlink, array

```
if [[ "$1" == "" ]]
 then

leftarray=($(find . -type l -printf "%p\n" 2>/dev/null))
rightarray=($(find . -type l -printf "%l\n" 2>/dev/null))

for var in "${rightarray[@]}"
do
   maximumarray[$index]=`echo "$var" | tr -dc "/" | wc -c | tr -d " "`
   index=$(($index+1))
done
#############
for numbers in "${maximumarray[@]}"
do
   if [[ $numbers > $MAX  ]]
   then
   MAX=$numbers
   fi
done
#############
for var in "${rightarray[@]}"
do

   component=`echo "$var" |  tr -dc "/" | wc -c | tr -d " "`
        if [[ $component -eq $MAX  ]]
        then
        echo "Output: '${leftarray[$temp]} -> ${rightarray[$temp]}'"
        fi
   emp=$(($temp + 1))
done
```

Here's the problem
When running script without arguments or switches it should search through all directories and subdirectories of directory where you are.
It does not work and I do not know why and it drives me crazy.

This script should find the symbolic link with longest number of `"/"` in `-printf "%l\n"` and output it. It should work when there are more links with same number of "/"

this script have also switch `-d <number>` and it has the same code as above but in find i use also -maxdepth and it works fine so I do not know why this does not work.

Any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the additional information provided by the OP, the solution is this.

The conditional line `if [[ $numbers > $MAX  ]]` is not yielding the desired result.  By changing the `>` to `-gt` the script works as expected.

From the bash manpage under CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS:

```
string1 > string2
          True if string1 sorts after string2 lexicographically in the current locale.

arg1 OP arg2
       OP is one of -eq, -ne, -lt, -le, -gt, or -ge.  These arithmetic binary operators return true if arg1  is  equal  to,  not
          equal  to, less than, less than or equal to, greater than, or greater than or equal to arg2, respectively.  Arg1 and arg2
          may be positive or negative integers.
```

Comment: i checked it and it is in my code maybe i erased it when i was formating it here.but still find is not working good. in my test it should find two links with number of "/" equal to ten byt instead of it it will find links with number of "/" equal to 9 but i dont know why. maybe it will not search all subdirectories but i do not think that there is problem maybe problem is in countimg "/" because there are files an subdirectoriies with " " in name but i tested it and it worked ok with files of that type

Comment: @xpukm  I modified my answer as a result of the additional information you supplied.  Please modify your question to include this data as it is necessary to find a solution.